# Helpful answer needs to be undeleted

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

Not sure why my valid answer to a question was deleted
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27657674/674863

It answers the original question by allowing the person asking the question upgrade to Angular 1.3 without having to drop IE8 support. Benefiting from new features while not alienating their IE8 user base. Seems like a win-win to me.

The answer:

> I have Angular 1.3 working with IE8.
>
> It requires jQuery, a couple of shims and one source code change to Angular. I'm maintaining builds of Angular with a lot of the shims baked in and instructions on what else to include here: https://github.com/fergaldoyle/angular.js-ie8-builds
>
> I can't get the unit tests running properly with IE8 so can't confirm 100% compatibility, but using a broad smoke test I can confirm every feature I've ever used with Angular works fine in IE8 + 1.3

Comment: The moderator who deleted it would have to explain specifically, but I'd suspect it's because it has no meaningful content here in the post itself. It's pretty much just an advertisement for your project and a link, and if the link is unavailable for some reason there is zero useful content. Questions should be self-sustaining, with any links for providing additional information and not primary content.

Comment: The biggest issue I have is your answer does not really provide an answer to the question.  The actual content of the answer is hiding behind a github link.  On Stack Overflow, we expect that the main content of the answer actually be in the answer itself and not an external link.

Comment: You'd have to delete several answers to the same question if you followed that logic. I could post the 900kb+ of source code but I suspect that might be deleted too.

Comment: Most of the answers matching that style you used are older answers in which were posted when such answers were accepted.  I comment, downvote, and/or flag them when I see them now because they are no longer considered acceptable.  Given the current community answer guidelines, posts like the one you left are best left as comments and not answers.  The reason is if your github repository went away, your answer would contain absolutely zero useful information.  Posting your entire source, as you expected, would not be welcome.  But someone else might have another idea.

Comment: You could have made a short list of features that you had to patch (because those don't work in IE8). That would answer the question. As a bonus you give a link to the patched repo.

Comment: There are in fact 4 other answers to the question that *were* deleted for the same reason (which 10K+ users can see). Like yours, they contain no meaningful information other than a link to an off-site resource,.

Comment: How is a question asking to get a specific question restored a duplicate of any other question? How is that even possible?

Comment: @Fergal Your answer was deleted because you posted the exact same answer to multiple questions, the second one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27656991/426671).  If your verbiage is identical then that makes it seem that the question is a duplicate and should be closed as such.  You shouldn't be copying/pasting identical answers to multiple questions, your answer should be specific to each question asked.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The original question was actually multiple questions. One of them was

> Are there any patches that enable the use of AngularJS 1.3 in IE 8?

I think your answer to this question was completely appropriate.

The OP asked if there were any patches available, and I doubt he was expecting someone to copy and paste source code. A link would be the only appropriate answer, which you provided.

My guess is that your answer was removed by someone who didn't read the OP's entire question.